# R: plot distribution of a continuous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset containing the length of interviews people needed in order to fill out an online questionnaire.
Can someone please tell me, how I can plot a distribution of a continuous variable (`geom_line`) so that I can say

- 10% of the participants had 10 seconds or less
- 20% of the participants had 20 seconds or less

...

- 100% of the participants had 100 seconds or less

Let's assume that the times are normally distributed:

```r
df <- data.frame(length = rnorm(n = 8000, mean = 100, sd = 20) )
```

On the x-axis should be the proportion of the participants and on the y-axis the duration.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ecdf` which gives proportion as a function of length:

```
plot(ecdf(df$length))
```

[image]

And the other way round to get proportion on x axis as requested:

```
f <- ecdf(df$length)
df$proportion <- f(df$length)

ggplot(df)+geom_line(aes(proportion,length))
```

[image]

Comment: The ggplot equivalent is without `ecdf`, simply `ggplot(df, aes(length)) + stat_ecdf()`.

Comment: (The two plots are very different ...)

Comment: @r2evans, other way round to answer OP's question : x = proportion, & thanks for comment on `stat_ecdf`

Comment: okay, that's an interpretation (that I did not get the first time I read it), but that means still that one of your plots is incorrect. But the ggplot-idiomatic way (if avoiding an explicit call to `ecdf` is desired), could be `ggplot(df, aes(length)) + stat_ecdf() + coord_flip()`. (Before this I didn't know of `stat_ecdf`, so I'm learning here :-)